# Escutcheon plate doesn't cover hole in tiled shower wall

Tags: bathroom, shower, bathroom-fixtures

I just installed a new shower system and the new escutcheon plate is a little smaller than the old one, leaving a small gap at the bottom of the wall.

It's not terribly noticeable, so I'm not too concerned about it looking bad.

Any ideas on the easiest way to seal this up?

[image]

Comment: Definitely do not leave that gap open; you do **NOT** want water behind your tile. If you don't care about how it looks then fill it with 100% silicone caulk. I would personally just shop for a larger escutcheon plate.

Comment: To follow on with @MonkeyZeus' thought - contact the mfgr to see if they make a larger plate for that model of faucet. That's pretty snazzy, and I'm sure you don't want to ruin the look with any old generic silver plate just because it's big enough to cover the hole.

Comment: Thanks guys I think I agree. Im going to see if I can find a bigger escutcheon plate. If I can't ill caulk it up, but I agree I dont want a cheap look!

Comment: please post a picture without the escutcheon

Comment: Do you have tile?

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour].

Comment: Is this only a shower? At standing height how’s this look or appear? I would guess I would not even see it but I am 6’5”.

Answer (score 2):

I have run into this several times, the least expensive method I have found is to remove the plate and use grout, epoxy grout in this case I can’t tell if there is backing but hot glue on a paint stir stick really works , any epoxy that is fast setting could also hold something in place. Then fill with the appropriate color (white in this case) grout. I like the epoxy grout for things like this because it seals better.

You might say the color will be off as new grout even from the same bag will look different but in a small area like that the fixture changes the look also. In a few months it will look about the same and is not noticed by most unless they do this type of work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like large patch jobs for this. They look like patch jobs and completely ruin your lovely aesthetic. If you can find a matching plate to install behind this escutcheon, go that route. Otherwise I'd work with tile:

Find a matching or coordinating tile with bullnose edgers. **Overlay a decorative tile mosaic** using construction adhesive or mastic (suitable for bonding to non-porous surfaces). I would split a large tile horizontally, vertically, or diagonally (possibly twice), *or* use four or more smaller tiles centered on the plumbing. Then wrap those with the bullnose tile. The only consideration is that the overlaying tiles must be large enough to comfortably span over the existing hole or you'll need to provide backing.

This depends on you having depth available behind the escutcheon, of course. It may require a shift of the valve body to accommodate.